# amchart v3 gantt chart value axis fix interval

Tags: amcharts

I want to create a gnatt chart with the value axis interval fixed as year in a interval if 1yr eg. 2019, 2020 etc. 
Below is the codepen for the data I am working with

https://codepen.io/keziah91/pen/oNgdNMM

Came across the below solution but not sure how to get this in v3 format.
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/

```
// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  "timeUnit": "year",
  "count": 5
};
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
```

Comment: Which version of amCharts are you using? The firs snippet seems for V3, the link and second snippet is from V4.

Comment: I am using V3. I just tried to use flags from based on v4 code snippet.

Comment: It would be easier for everyone to help you if you posted what you have so far as a CodePen or jsFiddle.

Comment: I have posted a codepen for my chart. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, used

```
"valueAxis": {
      "type": "date",
      "minPeriod" : "YYYY"
    },
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "period": "YYYY",
    "startDate" : "2018-01-01"
```

Graph that I wanted to fix 
https://codepen.io/keziah91/pen/oNgdNMM

Fixed intervals to years
https://codepen.io/keziah91/pen/ExaEEZX